# Getting my AJAX/PHP contact form to send email

Tags: php, ajax

I've looked at various solutions but I just can't get my contact form to work. **The issue im having is that the email wont actually send out to me, everything works client side but I dont get the email. So I have come here to surely get the duplicate question label. Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" class="reply" id="contact" action="process.php">
                       <fieldset>
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <label>Name: <span>*</span></label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" required>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <label>Email: <span>*</span></label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" required>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <label>Subject: <span>*</span></label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" type="text" value="" required>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <label>Message: <span>*</span></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="text" name="text" rows="3" cols="40" required></textarea>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </fieldset>
                       <button class="btn btn-normal btn-color submit  bottom-pad" type="submit">Send</button>
                       <div class="success alert-success alert" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</div>
                       <div class="error alert-error alert" style="display:none">E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 100 characters.</div>
                       <div class="clearfix">
                       </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is my process.php

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) &&     isset($_POST['text']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

// detect & prevent header injections
$test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
  exit;
}
}


        // PREPARE THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
        $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . htmlentities($_POST['text']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";



        //   CHANGE THE BELOW VARIABLES TO YOUR NEEDS

        $to = 'iknowichange@this.com';

        $subject = $_POST['subject'];

        $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


}
?>
```

I am completely new to forms, so thanks in advance for the help. If there are any resources that you can suggest that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly does this fail?  Is the form posted to the server?  Are the server-side values what you expect them to be?  Does the PHP code execute as you expect it to?  Is the mail sent and you're just not seeing it in your inbox?  You need to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot to include an action in your form element. 
(Unless your binding an onsubmit event somewhere else)

Try

```
<form method="post" class="reply" id="contact" action="process.php">
```

Comment: Added and tested but still not getting an email. Definitely appreciate the help though.

Comment: Try echoing $message "echo $message;" So when you submit you can see what your email should look like.  I would also var_dump($_POST); It's useful for debugging

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any action in your form element. You've to set the path of your "process.php" in form element like following:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact" class="reply">
    ...
</form>
```

More about form: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Added and tested but still not getting an email. Definitely appreciate the help though.

Comment: I've tested your code in runnable.com. It's working perfectly and gets all the input values. Not sure whats problem you're facing. Check the code here: [http://runnable.com/me/U7r1C4CT99QtyPgo](http://runnable.com/me/U7r1C4CT99QtyPgo) .